# How do I import an excel spreadsheet where there is a date column that has text and numerical date formats? eg, ("3-Dec-19", "2019-05-04", "43787"

Tags: r, excel, lubridate

If I have multiple spreadsheets with date column that have different formats, is it possible to convert the dates if some of the rows have the numeric format?

If I import the columns as character, I would still need to convert to date. I believe parse_date_time will fix anything accept the number format.

The following will convert the first two but not the numeric version. I don't think this function has a numeric function.
Is there a function that can process both Text and Numeric dates?

```
x<- c("2019-12-05","8-Dec-19","43787")
lubridate::parse_date_time(x, c("ymd", "d-b-y"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit clunky, but you can take a second pass through the data with `janitor::excel_numeric_to_date()` for any values that are numeric and failed to parse via `parse_date_time` ...  (if you're going to use this often, you can write a wrapper function - you might also want to suppress the warning messages from `parse_date_time` and `as.numeric` ...)

```r
x <- c("2019-12-05","8-Dec-19","43787")
y <- lubridate::parse_date_time(x, c("ymd", "d-b-y"))
exceld <- is.na(y) & !is.na(as.numeric(x))
y[exceld] <- janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(x[exceld]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a better approach, but I was able to create a function that handles both the numeric and text versions of the date format with the tryFormats.

```
dfix(c("2019-12-05","8-Dec-19","43787"))
```

[1] "2019-12-05" "2019-12-08" "2019-11-18"

```
dfix<-function(x1){
  dout<-c()
  for (x in x1){
    if(grepl('\\d{5}',x)){ #Check for numeric date (5 digits)
      n<-as.numeric(x)
      d<-as.Date(n, origin = "1899-12-30")
    }
    else if (grepl('-',x)){ # TryFormats for dates with "-" 
      d<-as.Date(x,tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d","%d-%b-%y"))
    }
    dout<-c(dout,d)
  }
  
  return (as.Date(dout,origin = '1970-01-01'))
}
```

Comment: did my approach work? It's basically the same as yours ...

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. (I didn't have the janitor package so I used the base functions)